# Ayuda con consulta en sql server

Tags: laravel, sql-server-2008

tengo la siguiente duda, necesito filtrar una consulta en sql server por rango de fechas y rango de horas, para ello realice el siguiente query:

```
SELECT * FROM AHUMA00016 WHERE 
Fecha BETWEEN '28/5/18' AND '29/5/18' AND Hora BETWEEN '09:13' AND '09:28';
```

pero esto me regresa en el rango de fechas, fechas diferentes a las especificadas en el rango, se me ocurrió que podría hacer una consulta por rango de horas sobre el rango de fechas especificado, no se como hacer muy bien esto a ver si de pronto alguno me podría ayudar con ello, muchas gracias!

Posdata: 
La idea seria luego implementar la consulta en laravel, pero primero quisiera tener claridad sobre como hacer la consulta correctamente

Estructura de la tabla:

[image: estructura de la tabla:]

Algunos de los resultado que arroja:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, incluye *como texto* la definición de la tabla sobre la que estas haciendo la consulta.

Comment: perdón un poco mi ignorancia, pero a que te refieres cuando dices definición de la tabla amigo?

Comment: Estás haciendo SELECT FROM AHUMA00016. Cómo está definida esa tabla AHUMA00016? Cuáles campos tiene, de qué tipo, puedes incluso poner unos datos de prueba para ver por qué no esta mostrando lo que quieres

Comment: @Alfabravo listo amigo, ahí adjunte datos mas precisos

Comment: between no te va a servir con esa estructura de tabla, porque esa función te calcula intervalos para las fechas (creo) pero cuando son date o datetime. Con varchar te vas a sacar un ojo manejando fechas. Para qué usar varchar si tienes un tipo de dato que te maneja eso?

Comment: es correcto @Alfabravo lo que sucede es que esa base de datos me la han entregado de esa manera, realmente no fui yo quien la realizo pero tiene ese defecto con ese tipo de dato, habría alguna solución sin tener la necesidad de alterar el tipo de dato?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que de la forma en que tienes tu Query te va a traer lo que este dentro del rango de fechas sin importa la hora y lo que este dentro del rango de horas sin importar las fechas, debes de agrupar las condiciones de la siguiente manera:

**Esto para cuando tus campos son Date o Datetime que es lo más recomendable**

```
SELECT * FROM AHUMA00016 WHERE 
(Fecha BETWEEN '28/5/18' AND '29/5/18') AND (Hora BETWEEN '09:13' AND '09:28');
```

Dada tu situación se me ocurre que crees una vista con los campos que ocupas de esa tabla y los campos de fecha y hora les apliques un cast y despues apliques tu select sobre esa vista, seria algo así:

```
CREATE VIEW VistaFecha AS 
SELECT CAST(Fecha as DATE) 'FechaDate', CAST(Hora AS Time) 'HoraTime'
FROM AHUMA00016
```

Ya despues ahora si haces la consulta normal pues los campos seran Date y Time respectivamente.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta y ayuda ! acabo de probar el query pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema :( lo que sucede es que el rango de horas esta bien, pero en el rango de las fechas el mes debería de ser siempre el mes 5 y resulta que se pasa, un ejemplo de lo que me arroja en las fechas y que es erróneo es esto (28/6/18, 28/7/18) cuando debería ser del (28/5/18 - 29/5/18) lo único que debería variar deberían ser los días

Comment: @SebastianRodriguez si nos muestras cómo está definida tu tabla, creo que no tendrías este lío con las respuestas que te dan. Por favor, edita tu pregunta

Comment: oh vale perfecto! ya la edito!

Comment: El campo fecha es de tipo Date o es de tipo Varchar?

Comment: varchar @shop350

Comment: @SebastianRodriguez ¿Por que tu campos no son Date y time correspondientemente?

Comment: @M.Gress asi me la han entregado bro :( y no he querido modificarla debido a que así es como la están usando en la empresa a la que le hago el desarrollo

Comment: Que mal amigo @SebastianRodriguez y para acabarla es nvarchar, ocupando espacio sin necesidad alguna, editare mi respuesta proponiendo otra alternativa aunque no es l omás recomendable.

Comment: si bro @M.Gress intentare hablar con ellos sin embargo para hacerles la sugerencia, de igual manera quisiera tener otra opción a la mano en caso tal que no se pueda hacer el cambio del tipo de dato

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta, prueba con ello. @SebastianRodriguez

Comment: @M.Gress en efecto bro tu solución funciona! solo tengo una única pregunta y perdón mi ignorancia, no se mucho de sql server... si la tabla base, se llena con mas datos, la vista también lo hace? lo digo porque esas tablas se llenan constantemente en tiempo real :(

Comment: @SebastianRodriguez Así es bro, cada vez que ejecutas esta vista va y trae los datos de todas las tablas involucradas, los datos que muestre tu vista siempre sera lo que haya en tu tabla en tiempo real.

Comment: @M.Gress muchas gracias amigo, tu solución fue perfecta para arreglar el problema en la base de datos!

Comment: @SebastianRodriguez No olvides marcar la respuesta como solución :) Y tampoco olvides que lo ideal es que desde tu tabla los campos sean del tipo que deben de ser.

Comment: @M.Gress Hola amigo, disculpa la molestia... te quería preguntar si tal vez de la forma que me indicaste hace unos días para convertir los tipos de datos fecha y horas en date  y time, habría forma de unir estos 2 campos y crear un date time, resulta que tengo que hacer una consulta un poco "compleja" pero va a ser necesario sobre ese tipo de dato(datetime)

Comment: @SebastianRodriguez Puede que si, deberias de armar el DateTime a manita es decir concatenar char por char para pasarlo a una columna DateTime

Comment: @M.Gress me podrías de pronto un ejemplo para yo guiarme bro ? :(